# How to use Bootstrap-select?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, select

I’m new to this. I’m trying the **Bootstrap-select** but I’m not getting the desired effect like here https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/. I have downloaded the files and pointed to the CSS and JS in the head. I have enabled Bootstrap-select via JavaScript in the head as well and still not working – I’m just getting the default appearance. Here is my complete code. What am I doing wrong here? Any tips will be appreciated.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link href="bootstrap-master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap-master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="bootstrap-master/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      style: 'btn-info',
      size: 4
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forgot to import jquery first

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem.  Here is a working example for anyone coming to this question later like I did.

Note there are **2 CSS** files and **3 JavaScript** files you must include.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    size: 4
  });
});
```

Your script is declared and therefore executed *before* the `<select class="selectpicker">` -declaration, causing bootstrap-select never being initialized opon `.selectpicker` (selectpicker doesnt exists when the script is runned). So put it in a `document(ready)` or after the HTML.

Comment: Hi davidkonrad, I have done both these suggestions but still not rendering as it should be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Include jquery library and bootstrap js

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-master/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and code as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      style: 'btn-info',
      size: 4
  });
  });
```

**Note:**
Always used minified css and js, to increase page speed

Comment: Thanks Tamil. I have included this 


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

but still not rendering as intended

Comment: I have included it in the html, after the <select> tags.

Comment: add the scripts above the bootstrap-select.js

Answer (score 3):

After 1 year I had the same issue. This worked for me:

1-Downloaded the zip files at owner site - https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

2-CSS, inside head tag->2files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourPath/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-83d5a1b/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<link href="yourPath/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

3-Js files, at the end before close bode tag.

```
<body>
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-83d5a1b/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  });
</script>
</body>
```